# Python Selenium Webdriver - Unable to locate element when removing Facebook post

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a Python script to help me delete my excess facebook group posts using Selenium Webdriver and I have encountered a problem where Selenium is not able to locate an element.

The error I am getting is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="post_menu"]/div/ul/li[10]/a"}
```

My code looks like this:

```
import os
import string
import time
import requests
import config
import re
import random
from tinytag import TinyTag
from clint.textui import progress
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(60)

browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/group_id/yourposts/?availability=available&referral_surface=your_posts_unsold_notif")
browser.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)

browser.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("email")
browser.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("password")
print("Logging in ...")

browser.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
print("Logged in ...")

mainWindowHandle = browser.window_handles
print "main window handle: %s" %mainWindowHandle

elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "mall_post_")]')
for element in elements:
  allWindowsHandlesList = browser.window_handles
  print "all window handles: %s" %allWindowsHandlesList

  id = element.get_attribute("id")[10:]
  link_x_path = "//*[@id='mall_post_%s']/div/div[1]/a" % (id)
  link = browser.find_element_by_xpath(link_x_path)
  actions = ActionChains(browser)
  actions.move_to_element(link).perform()

  time.sleep(4)
  link.click()

  delete = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post_menu"]/div/ul/li[10]/a')
  delete.click()
```

The problem occurs when I try to locate the Delete link which is probably loaded by Javascript:

```
delete = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post_menu"]/div/ul/li[10]/a')
```

This is the li that contains the link, I am getting the Xpath by copying the link from the Chrome inspector, there is an option to copy the Xpath.

```
<li class="_54ni _41t6 __MenuItem" role="presentation">
<a class="_54nc" href="#" rel="async-post"
ajaxify="/ajax/groups/mall/delete/?group_id=874536857643876&amp;post_id=7836284732687326&amp;story_dom_id=u_fetchstream_3_o&amp;entstory_context=%7B%22last_view_time%22%3A1532623110%2C%22fbfeed_context%22%3Atrue%2C%22location_type%22%3A3%2C%22outer_object_element_id%22%3A%22u_fetchstream_3_o%22%2C%22object_element_id%22%3A%22u_fetchstream_3_o%22%2C%22is_ad_preview%22%3Afalse%2C%22is_editable%22%3Afalse%2C%22mall_how_many_post_comments%22%3A2%2C%22bump_reason%22%3A0%2C%22enable_comment%22%3Afalse%2C%22story_width%22%3A502%2C%22tn-str%22%3A%22-R%22%7D&amp;surface=group_post_chevron&amp;location=3" role="menuitem">
<span><span class="_54nh">
<div class="_41t5">
<i class="_41t7 img sp_PBbYkTGVdjY_2x sx_92b175"></i>
<i class="_41t8 img sp_4Wahr7NwMMo_2x sx_7864af"></i>
Delete post</div></span></span></a>
</li>
```

After the above link is clicked, it will open a popup window asking if you are sure that you want to delete the post and this is the Delete button that needs to be clicked:

```
<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 layerConfirm uiOverlayButton _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy" data-testid="delete_post_confirm_button" type="submit">Delete</button>
```

The link looks like this:

[facebook delete post link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZrDI.png)

The code in the Google Chrome Inspector looks like this:

[Google Chrome Inspector Delete post link code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr1Ha.png)

Any help is appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: Does it work if you add a break before the `delete = ` line and letting it load first then let your code continue?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be `importing` ***WebDriverWait***, but not using it. If you include the correct wait conditions into your script, and replace your `time.sleep()` calls as well, you will have a more consistent and *working* selenium script.

Here is an example using your code above:

> NOTE: this code is untested, and built in Python 3, you appear to be
>   using Python 2, but it should still work as is.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/groups/group_id/yourposts/?availability=available&referral_surface=your_posts_unsold_notif")
browser.maximize_window()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'email'))).send_keys("email")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'pass'))).send_keys("password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'loginbutton'))).click()
print("Logged in ...")

mainWindowHandle = browser.window_handles
print ("main window handle: %s" %mainWindowHandle)

elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "mall_post_")]')))
for element in elements:
    allWindowsHandlesList = browser.window_handles
    print ("all window handles: %s" %allWindowsHandlesList)

    element_id = element.get_attribute("id")[10:]
    link_x_path = "//*[@id='mall_post_%s']/div/div[1]/a" % element_id
    link = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, link_x_path)))
    actions = ActionChains(browser)
    actions.move_to_element(link).perform()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, link_x_path))).click()

    #the wait here should resolve the AJAX load issue that caused your element to not be found    
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="uiContextualLayerPositioner uiLayer"]/div/div[@id="post_menu"]/div/ul/li[10]/a'))).click()
```

As long as all of your *locators* are correct, you should now be able to click the delete button.

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue, it's raising a TimeoutException on: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="post_menu"]/div/ul/li[10]/a'))).click()

Comment: I am not sure of the `xpath` you are using to find the delete key. Can you add more of the ***HTML*** to your question (please don't use a picture)? With proper formatting so I can build a good path for you.

Comment: I just edited the question to add the code.
Do you think my Xpath is not good?
I am getting the Xpath by copying the link from the Chrome inspector, there is an option to copy the Xpath.
Appreciate your effort to help, thanks a lot!

Comment: When you click on the button that opens up the menu to select the delete, do you an element above with this `class="uiContextualLayerPositioner uiLayer"`?

Comment: When you have the inspector open, and you click the button to open up the menu, you should see the menu tree in the dom change, can you give me all the HTML from the div that changes when the button is clicked to open the menu down through the delete option?

Comment: Or just all the ***HTML*** from the element above the `id="post_menu"` and down to the delete? I am trying to recreate your scenario and am having a hard time because I do not have your exact HTML. I think I know what is causing this issue though.

Comment: What do you think the issue is? I am not able to edit the original post again, but I have copied the HTML from the element above id="post_menu" down to the delete and saved it here: http://pasted.co/dec01c4b

Comment: Okay, I updated the **XPATH** with what I think should solve your issue, but I believe it's because there are multiple elements with the same XPATH that are ***HIDDEN*** that cause the issue, with going to the element above and selecting by the class that does not include `hidden_elem` in the class, it should work.